# Performance of auto_ptr vs. shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

I didn't find information about performance issues with **auto_ptr** and **shared_ptr**(I use *tr1* implementation). As shared_ptr is more complicated compared to auto_ptr so auto_ptr is faster? So in general question sounds like what can you say about performance of shared_ptr with comparison with auto_ptr?

PS: I know that now unique_ptr is preferable than auto_ptr, but not all compilers support it, so question is about auto_ptr and shared_ptr

Comment: There's probably a reason you didn't find such information. It's apples to oranges.

Comment: You should build a realistic use-case and profile it.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: not really, no. It's a valid question with an answer that one might not have guessed without, uh, reading the documentation...

Comment: It's not really apples to oranges.  Its more like Fuji apples to granny Smith apples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When dereferencing there are no performance differences.
2. If you allocate your shared_ptr's with make_shared you don't waste any heap allocations.
3. When copying the pointer (not the object), a shared_ptr is a little bit slower because it needs to increase it's reference counter.

However, these probably does not matter, so stick with shared_ptr combined with make_shared.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is greedy, once it grabs hold of a pointer it never let's go (without deleting it), which to me is the most limiting factor. `unique_ptr` or `auto_ptr` can both relinquish ownership and allow the user to select any other type of pointer they may want.

Comment: I agree with David. `shared_ptr` should not be your default smart pointer. It's heavy and it's forever.

Comment: @David: that's true, but it's not a comparison of the performance of the two. By definition you can only compare the performance of things that they both do. Things that only `auto_ptr` does, and `shared_ptr` doesn't, aren't part of a performance comparison. If the questioner needs facilities that `shared_ptr` doesn't have, then there's worse things wrong with this question than just the risk of somebody advising the use of `shared_ptr` :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Then the cost of *copying* should also be out of the equation, should it not?

Comment: @David: heh, maybe. In C++ terms an `auto_ptr` can be copied, via its copy constructor and copy assignment operator. In normal English it's not really a copy, since it modifies the original, but that's standardese for you.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes And it is unreliable---it can't handle cycles (admittedly, `auto_ptr`s way of avoiding them is somewhat brutal), and above all, if you make a `shared_ptr` twice from the same raw pointer, you're in deep trouble.

Comment: @James: if you make an `auto_ptr` twice from the same raw pointer, you're in deep trouble. I can't think of a smart pointer that doesn't have this property. In theory you could create a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` with a do-nothing deleter, in addition to the smart pointer that's actually handling the resource, but in practice I think that'd be a workaround for a broken API, not a genuine example of what you're calling "reliability".

Answer (score 2):

`auto_ptr` is a deprecated C++98 construct. As such, any performance benefit it *might* have is far outweighed by the fact that you shouldn't use it anymore in newly-written C++11 code, and instead badger the compiler / library maintainers to implement support for `unique_ptr`.

That being said, use what *semantically* fits your use case, unless you have *profiled* that you have a problem with `*_ptr`...

Answer (score 1):

In general the only good answer is to **measure**.

But for this case you know that `shared_ptr`, unless you're using `make_shared` it involves a dynamic allocation of a counter block, and unless you have a really good small objects allocator, it's bound to be really slow (talking orders of magnitude) to create the first shared pointer to an object.

But then, perhaps with Boost and the standard library that allocation is really optimized. And maybe, probably!, you can use `make_shared` to use just 1 allocation for both the object and its control block. So … *measure*.

By the way, `auto_ptr` is deprecated.

With any modern compiler use `unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: Hmmm.  It's only been a year since the standard has been adopted.  It usually takes compiler writers five or more years for the new features to stabilize to the point where they can be used in production code.  I'd says that `auto_ptr` is the way to go for most production code today.

Comment: @JamesKanze I see the practicality of your point, but it *is* the new standard, so why write code using a deprecated function? (It's deprecated in C++11 and people like Stephan Lavavej recommend not using it.)  Is `shared_ptr` really *that* experimental?

Comment: Anyway, `shared_ptr` is more-or-less the same as in TR1, which is 6 years old. It's not as though compiler writers were blindsided by its sudden invention, some time in late 2011, and if nothing else the Boost implementation is fine for most production uses. Granted, `unique_ptr` is newer, but it's pretty close to the simplest thing you can do with move semantics that isn't completely pointless. You might like to wait 5 years before using it anyway, depending how cautious you are about the quality of your compiler, but you *can* use it sooner.

Comment: Oh, and another option is to implement your own smart pointer which has the same operations as `auto_ptr` and `unique_ptr` (construct, destroy, release, transfer ownership), but which doesn't fixate on `operator=` as the way to transfer ownership, and hence is neither weird like `auto_ptr`, nor reliant on move like `unique_ptr`. Personally I would say that's strictly superior to `auto_ptr`, and hence if you're on an old compiler and dislike `shared_ptr`, do that.

Comment: @ChrisA. Because you can't yet write it using the new function, because your compiler doesn't support it, or its support hasn't been validated with sufficient use.  (My employer isn't in the compiler testing business.)  And deprecated doesn't mean that it will disappear immediately.  (I think some of the features deprecated in Fortran 66 are still around.)

Comment: @ChrisA. (and Steve) I'm not too worried about `unique_ptr`---as you say, it's not that new.  But to get it, I have to upgrade the compiler, and risk errors in other things.

Comment: @James: yep, that's fair enough. I see why you'd be averse to taking a new compiler, I just got myself puzzled thinking about why you'd avoid this new *feature* in the compiler you have. But that's not what you meant. Oops :-)

Answer (score 1):

As with all performance issues: you need to measure it for yourself in your particular setup.

In general, though, you can expect some more overhead for a `shared_ptr<>` than for `auto_ptr<>` as it has to do some more work behind the scene to ensure proper shared behavior for the enclosed pointer.

On the other hand, the two are not really comparable: `auto_ptr<>` supports only one copy (the ownership is transfered on copy), while `shared_ptr<>` supports multiple copies.  So unless you only use the above pointers for one copy-pointer, you cannot make a meaningful comparision.  If you *do* use one-copy pointer and you are sure you will not need more copies, use the specialized `auto_ptr<>`.

In any case, whether the performance differences are significant depends on your particular project.